# Using IUP library with Lua For Windows, how do I force iup.getparam and other predefined dialogs to always be on top?

Tags: lua, iup

I have several lua programs that use only the predefined dialogs of IUP.

Using IUP library with Lua For Windows, how do I force iup.getparam and other predefined dialogs to always be on top of other windows?

Here is a simple example:

```
require("iuplua")
local Status, NumCopies
Status, NumCopies = iup.GetParam('What do you want to do?', nil, 'How Many Copies do you want?%i\n',  NumCopies)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that relative to another window, usually the main window of the application, using the global attribute PARENTDIALOG. For instance:

```
iup.SetGlobal("PARENTDIALOG", main_dlg)
```